# RadixUI popover don't open when combined with Tooltip

Tags: reactjs, radix-ui

I tried to make `TooltipButton` and `PopoverButton` components to nicely nest them when needed. However, Popover won't open when doing it. Here is my demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tooltip-popover-forked-dh3zq3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A58%2C40

While tooltip works fine, popover won't open. What should I change? I would really like to have separate components for `Tooltip` and `Popover`.

In official docs they suggest to do the following: https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/guides/composition#composing-multiple-primitives

But I want to make my generic Tooltip and Popover buttons instead of mix it in a single component

Comment: Please see [ask]. Links to code on other sites aren't adequate.